# How to make table partition by created date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-optimization

Well, I have database ( Postgres ) and Rails as web-framework.

I want to know how to do table partitioning.

Ok, suppose, that I have table: `Events` and it has field `created_at`

This model use `act_as_paranoid` gem and these events didn't deleted at all. ( big amount of them, oh )

I want to do next thing: I want to make this table `Events` partitions by created_at field reduced to months.

Ok, I found some posts about it.

[Pure postres solution](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/scaling-postgresql-performance-table-partitioning) seems good.
[Presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/agnessa/table-partitioning-in-postgre-sql-rails) tells about different approaches.
[Partitioned gem](https://github.com/fiksu/partitioned) looks pretty simple for usage.

I need a point to start.
Gem doesn't provide good examples for my task.
Postgres solution doesn't correlate with my knowledge of database management and seems pretty bad ( do I need any migrations or any new schemes? ).
And presentation contains only overview.

Suppose, that I have this class to start:

```
class ByCreatedAtField < Partitioned::ByMonthlyTimeField
    self.abstract_class = true
    belongs_to :event

    def self.partition_time_field
        return :created_at
    end
end
```

Also I have:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
# code-cod-e-co-de-c-ode
end
```

Ok, I could replace `ActiveRecord::Base` superclass to my specified partition.
`ByCreatedAtField`.

```
class Event < ByCreatedAtField
# code-cod-e-co-de-c-ode
end
```

And I stuck here.

Which migrations should I apply to database to make my table partitioned?

How to retrieve table `Event` by specified month?

I need more explanations about further table partitioning deployment.

Thanks for time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this exemple for the gem : https://github.com/fiksu/partitioned/blob/master/examples/start_date.rb

Try changing start_date by created_at and you should get the desired result.